# ¿Porque cuando añado un elemento a un JPanel no se ven los cambios hasta que cambio el tamaño de la ventana?

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo una lista a la que se pueden añadir elementos y cuando añado un elemeno no se puede ver hasta que cambio  un poco el tamaño de la ventana. Los elementos de la lista son JPanel y los añado simplemente con add(); si alguien pudiese explicarme porque pasa o alguna manera de solucionarlo se lo agradeceria mucho.

Este es un programa diferente pero que da el mismo problema (pongo este porque el otro es demasiado largo)

Este lo que hace es que crea un JPanel con un boton y cuando pulsas al boton va creando otros botones. La cosa es que esos botones no se ven hasta que se pasa el boton por encima o se redimensiona la ventana.

```
public class principal {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
            Pantalla mi_frame = new Pantalla(500,500);
            Velo mi_panel = new Velo();
            mi_frame.add(mi_panel);
            mi_frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
}


class Pantalla extends JFrame
{
    public Pantalla(int width,int height)
    {
        setSize(new Dimension(width,height));
        setLocation(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().width/2-width/2,Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().height/2-height/2);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}

class Velo extends JPanel
{
    int X=50;
    int contador=0;
    
    public Velo()
    {
        setLayout(null);
        JButton mi_boton = new JButton("Añadir boton");
        mi_boton.setBounds(100, 20, 150, 30);
        mi_boton.addActionListener(new Escuchador());
        add(mi_boton);
    }
    
    class Escuchador implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            
            JButton nuevo_boton = new JButton(""+contador);
            contador++;
            nuevo_boton.setBounds(X,100, 45, 30);
            X+=50;
            add(nuevo_boton);
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Tienes la suficiente reputación para saber como se pregunta. Deberías de mostrar tu código, pues así la gente podrá auditarlo y darte una respuesta. Un saludo

Comment: @el.trasgu es verdad pero esque normalmente hago las preguntas sobre c que tengo por así decirlo más experiencia y se entiende mejor mi código pero esque en java creo que no es muy comprensible para otras personas . Pero lo intentaré

Comment: @julianix te recomiendo echar un vistazo a la [convención de nombres](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convenci%C3%B3n_de_nombres_(programaci%C3%B3n)#Java) de Java, esto ayuda a que el código sea más fácil de entender para los demás.

Comment: Llama a `repaint()` despúes de `add(nuevo_boton)`.

Comment: @David Chinchilla  muchas gracias. asi podre hacer preguntas un poco mas comprensibles XD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que estás agregando un elemento al `JFrame` pero no lo estás actualizando (pintando), por eso es que cuando pasas el puntero por donde debería estar el botón, o cuando redimensionas la ventana, el botón sí se ve; porque estás forzando al JFrame a actualizarse.
¿Cómo lo solucionas entonces?

Tienes que llamar al método `paint()` después de agregar el nuevo botón (o elemento), de esta manera estás actualizando al `JFrame` justo después de agregar el botón y es visible instantáneamente.

```
class Escuchador implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JButton nuevo_boton = new JButton("" + contador);
            contador++;
            nuevo_boton.setBounds(X, 100, 45, 30);
            X += 50;
            add(nuevo_boton);
            paint(getGraphics());
        }
    }
```

Lo probé con el código que subiste y funciona perfectamente, si en tu otro proyecto se trata del mismo problema también debería funcionar.